How to Include LightGBM 4.5 to Visual C++ Project?
I want to use C API LightGBM in My Visual C++ Project? How do I do it? I attach My code ??
DatasetHandle dataset_handle;

// load dataset

int result;
    result = LGBM_DatasetCreateFromFile("D:\\2- Anode Effect\\Project2\\DataMining\\DataMining\\AE_Salco_Dataset.csv", "label_column=11", nullptr, &dataset_handle);



  int max_iteration = 100;
BoosterHandle booster_handle;

    result =  LGBM_BoosterCreate(dataset_handle, "task=train objective=bineryclass metric=multi_logloss num_class=2 force_col_wise=true", &booster_handle);



int result_save;
                result_save = LGBM_BoosterSaveModel(booster_handle, 0, 0, C_API_FEATURE_IMPORTANCE_GAIN,"D:\\2- Anode Effect\\Project2\\DataMining\\DataMining\\trained_model.txt");

this->tBPrediction->Text = this->tBPrediction->Text + sStandardTosSystem("Model Booster Saved in trained_model.txt::==>  " + itos(result_save) + " \r\n");

I do not Know How I include LightGBM Library??

Please provide information about what happened when you tried to do this. Remember it's off-topic to ask for a tutorial.

If the problem is installation have you attempted these instructions: https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation-Guide.html#windows
